# Google Remarketing Javascript

Tags: javascript, magento, prototypejs, google-ads-api

I have some fancy JavaScript that is printed out from my Magento installation. It allows us to have our list of domains and if they have re-marketing lists we can enter in the details to kick off the re-marketing when the JS detects that we're on that domain.

Heres the code:

```
$protocol = Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure() ? 'https' : 'http';
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('google/analytics/active')) {
        return '';
    }
    $this->addText('<script src="'.$protocol.'://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
    $this->addText("
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    // This section finds all links that are outside of the current domain and adds a Google Analytics Cross-Domain Tracking Script
    // THIS IS ABSOLUTELY MAGICAL, SOMETIMES I LAUGH AT HOW CLEVER THIS LITTLE SNIPPET IS
    // I need to get out more
    var domains = {
        'whitestores.co.uk':false,
        'bbqsdirect.co.uk':false,
        'resinweavegardenfurniture-direct.co.uk':{
            'google_conversion_id':1069311156,
            'google_conversion_label':'BDWlCMy72AIQtMnx_QM'
        },
        'metalgardenfurnituredirect.co.uk':false,
        'teakgardenfurniture-direct.co.uk':false,
        'bistrosets-direct.co.uk':false,
        'firepits-direct.co.uk':false,
        'cushions-direct.co.uk':false,
        'benches-direct.co.uk':false,
        'parasols-direct.co.uk':false,
        'covers-direct.co.uk':false,
        'gardenbeanbags-direct.co.uk':false,
        'chimineas-direct.co.uk':false,
        'outdoorfurniture-direct.co.uk':false,
        'stores-direct.co.uk':false
    };

    // Get the current domain name
    var current_domain = document.domain.replace('www.','');

    // Go through each of the domain lists above, check that we aren't going to be affecting links
    // to the domain that we are currently on as this would be unnecessary.
    \$H(domains).each(function(pair){
        var val = pair.key;
        var options = pair.value;

        if(val == current_domain && options){
            console.log('This domain has remarketers');

            <!-- Google Code for Resin Weave Visitors Remarketing List -->

            var google_conversion_id = options['google_conversion_id'];
            var google_conversion_language = \"en\";
            var google_conversion_format = \"3\";
            var google_conversion_color = \"ffffff\";
            var google_conversion_label = \"options['google_conversion_label']\";
            var google_conversion_value = 0;

        }
        if(val != current_domain){

            // Check to see if there are 'a' elements in the code with any of the domains above in the HREF
            // If there is, go through each of them and add an on-click event utilising Google's link tracking feature
            if($(\"a[href*='\"+val+\"']\")){
                $(\"a[href*='\"+val+\"']\").each(function(elemindex,elem){
                    $(elem).click(function(){
                        _gaq.push(['_link',this.href]);
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            }

            // Do the same for forms
            if($(\"form[action*='\"+val+\"']\")){
                $(\"form[action*='\"+val+\"']\").each(function(elemindex,elem){
                    $(elem).attr('onSubmit',\"_gaq.push(['_linkByPost',this])\");
                });
            }

        }
    });

</script>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
//<![CDATA[
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount','UA-9852071-15']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
    _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    ".$this->getQuoteOrdersHtml()."
    (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
//]]>
 </script>
 ");
```

As you can see, this code also adds relevant Google Cross-Domain tracking attributes to links and forms but the issue is that my conversion script for remarketing isn't working. There are no Javascript errors but also no people showing in my remarketing list, we get around 50 visits to our site every couple of minutes so they should be there...

Desperately seeking a solution.

Hope to hear from someone

Dave

Comment: Apparently it's not magical *enough*...

Comment: Thanks for your insightful comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Davzie,

Firstly, what version of jQuery are you using as I don't recognise `$H(domains).each` as a jQuery function.  There is a `$H` function in Mootools, but [nothing in jQuery](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-prototype-h).

If you want to iterate through a jQuery object, you need to use

`$.each(your_array, function(index, value){}`

(This also applies to your bit on line 59 - `$(\"a[href*='\"+val+\"']\").each`)

Secondly, IE will fall over if you have any `console.log` entries in your code, only use these in a dev environment....

Hope that helps.

Touson